# Has Google removed the recent searches browser from the search app for Android?

Tags: google

I remember on the feature detail by this [article] (http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-search-gets-a-new-recent-tab-for-android-1672686) was introduced and enjoyed using it. Now it has disappeared without warning and I want it back. Can I reenable it?

[image]

Comment: I believe it didn't remove it. When I tap the search bar on my Android, It appears several suggestions of recent searches I've made... the UI might have changed, but not the functionality

Comment: No that had always existed but the special screen for viewing comprehensive search history, recently introduced, is now absent - see the picture

Comment: Just checked, the _Recent_ option is there, on Android 7.0, in the same place where the picture shows...

Comment: Not in my case. I triple checked before posting and again once more now.